# control of user input

Tags: python

I'm wondering why my input control here doesn't work. I tried it with only `userOption != "1"` and it worked fine (Side note: Ignore the other functions.)

```
userOption = str(input("Chose option 1, 2 or \"E/e to exit\": "))
print(userOption)
while(userOption != "1" or userOption != "2" or userOption != "e"
        or userOption != "E"):
    reply = (userOption + " is not a valid option")
    print(reply)
    userOption = input("Chose option 1, 2 or \"E/e to exit\": ")
    if userOption == "1":
        validEntry("Celsius")
        C_to_F(int(userInput))
        print(F)
    elif userOption == "2":
        validEntry("Fahrenheit")
        F_to_C(int(userInput))
        print(C)
    else:
        input("Thank you. Press enter to close this screen in the exe mode.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `and` instead of `or`

```
while userOption != "1" and userOption != "2" and userOption != "e" and userOption != "E":
```

or `not` with `==`

```
while not(userOption == "1" or userOption == "2" or userOption == "e" or userOption == "E"):
```

Or you can use `not in`

```
while userOption not in ("1", "2", "e", "E"):
```

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning that the last method is probably the clearest and most pythonic way. I do not know about its efficiency however.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry version with `tuple()` is probably most popular and should be fast but once I saw with `set()` which has `O(1)`: `while ... in {"1", "2", "e", "E"}:` :)

Comment: I believe your right. `set()` probably would be the better over `tuple()`. The OP however does not seem to be to concerned about performance though, so your solution would be ideal :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(userOption != "1" or userOption != "2" or userOption != "e"
    or userOption != "E"):
```

That logic will produce a true result *no matter what the user types*.  As others have said, you need to use `and` here instead of `or`.